# Issue with iOS storyboard view constraints

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa

i am having an issue with storyboard constraints, i have a map view, which i would like to have a variable height, depending on the screen size, e.g. (iPhone 4 & iPhone 5). The buttom section should contract and the mapkit height should contract with it. I am having a hard time understanding the constraints system, i have tried setting distance top & distance bottom to 0 & 0, i would expect that this gave the view a variable height, but it does not seem to be the case.

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

And this is how it looks on the iPhone 5, which is how its supposed to look.

[image]

**EDIT 1**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have read your question 3 times and am unsure of what you try to achieve.
So, the result is okay for iPhone5 but not for iPhone4. What do you want exactly to achieve for iPhone4? having the same height for both sections 1 and 2, and only having the height of section 3 decrease?

If so, it is quite easy:
- Put a height constraint for section 1 (height=X)
- Put a height constraint for section 2 (height=Y)
- Put a distance constraint between 3.Top and 2.Bottom (=0)
- Put a distance constraint between 3.Bottom and Superview.bottom (or Layout) (=0)

Comment: Still getting buttom overflow, il insert the image now

Comment: From what I see, I think the size of your "Detail View Controller Bottom" should be okay. Maybe the problem is in the subviews. If you add the constraints :  

- Height equals between Map and its superview (Detail View Controller Bottom)  
- Vertical space between your bottom left UIImageView and its superview  

Do you still have the issue?

Comment: When i do a height equals, i still get the bottom overflow, so the problem seems to be the detail view bottom

Comment: Okay, so I just created a empty project to test it. I managed to do it with the following constraints :  
- Vertical space between "Detail View Controller Top" and "Top Layout Guide"
- Height "Detail View Controller Top"
- Vertical space between "Detail View Controller Top" and "Detail View Controller Middle"
- Height "Detail View Controller Middle"
- Vertical space between "Detail View Controller Middle" and "Detail View Controller Bottom"
- Equal heights between "Detail View Controller Bottom" and its subview (your map)
- Vertical space between "Detail Bottom" and "Bottom Layout Space"

Comment: Sorry for poor formatting.  Can't manage to format properly comments... (tried the double space thing, didn't work)

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting your view controller (not the view!) in Interface Builder, at the utilities part select attributes inspector, and try toggling the checkboxes at the `Extend Edges` part. Additionaly, at your screenshot I see a red arrow symbol indicating that the system cannot satisfy the layout constraints, before all, make sure you satisfy all the constraints.

[image]

Comment: No effect i am afraid

Comment: @IvanRistic if you still see that arrow inside the red circle, you have something definitely wrong. don't try anything else before correcting that. what does it list when you click that arrow?